# Scrolling script for iOS 10 with Appium java client 5.0.0 and Appium version 1.6.4

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

Actually I know this will work for iOS 9.3 or below:

`findElementByIosUIAutomation(".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS '" + text + "'\")");`

But I want to do it for iOS 10 and looking for the scrolling script with 
`findElementByIosNsPredicate("????")`

Using Appium 1.6.4 with java client 5.0.0 Beta 7

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WebElement element = this.findElementByIosNsPredicate("name matches '"+ elementName + "'");
new TouchAction(driver).press(element, 0, 0).moveTo(element, 0, 0).release().perform();
```